# Suddenly, on a single machine, my auth token doesn’t run anymore

Tags: github

Suddenly, in the middle of the day, github ceased to work in one of my machines.

I just `git push` from my development machine, then I write down my `userid` and paste my `personal access token`. Done.

Just a few seconds later, I switch to my AWS online server, then I `git pull`, write down my `userid` and then pasted (from the same clipboard) my `personal access token`.

The answer has been

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/pdipietro/kebraServer/'
```

Now, on that machine (Ubuntu 20.04.3) I cannot do any git operation: the result is always the same as above.

On my development machine, and in other servers, I tried to `git push` and `git pull` that project and some others, and everything runs good as always.

I tried also to reboot the machine, without success.

Then, I generate new `personal access token` to my github, and tried with it, too: the same result.

At the end, I wrote this same post to the `github community`, but **Our automated spam filter, Akismet, has temporarily hidden your post**.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly, it restart to run correctly.

With no words for `github community`.

I have no words for this.